# How to remove the Show toolbar option for the users in KIWI TCMS

Tags: kiwi-tcms

KIWI TCMS is showing a Show toolbar option on the right side of the UI. Is there any way to remove this toolbar from the KIWI TCMS using permissions or any other way without changing the code?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another note:

you are running with DEBUG=True and most likely also using `./manage.py runserver`. Both of these are not recommended. The only way we recommend is using the docker image, otherwise we expect you to know what you are doing and be able to diagnose all possible issues by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the Show toolbar option change the tcms/settings/devel.py
Set DEBUG = False